# What is the problem with the shape of the roc curve with low auc(.4)?

Tags: matlab, svm

I'm trying to plot a ROC curve. I have 75 data points and I considered only 10 features. Ii'm getting a staircase like image see below. Is this due to the small data set? Can we add more points to improve the curve?
AUC is very low .44. Is there any method to upload csv file ?

```
species1= readtable('target.csv');
species1 = table2cell(species1)
meas1= readtable('feature.csv');
meas1=meas1(:,1:10);
meas1= table2array(meas1)
numObs = length(species1);

half = floor(numObs/2);
training = meas1(1:half,:);
trainingSpecies = species1(1:half);
sample = meas1(half+1:end,:);
trainingSpecies = cell2mat(trainingSpecies)
group = species1(half+1:end,:);
group = cell2mat(group)
SVMModel = fitcsvm(training,trainingSpecies)
[label,score] = predict(SVMModel,sample);

[X,Y,T,AUC] = perfcurve(group,score(:,2),'1');
plot(X,Y,'LineWidth',3)
xlabel('False positive rate')
ylabel('True positive rate')
title('ROC for Classification ')
```

[image: my ROC]

Comment: Perfcurve creates a threshold for every single point, when that happens, it will always be a stepwise plot.

Comment: There's nothing to solve here. This is just how it works. You could run a smoothing function I guess but that would degrade the quality.

Comment: which smoothing function

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by Durkee, the `perfcurve` function will always be stepwise. In fact, the ROC curve is an *empirical* (as opposed to *theoretical*) cumulative distribution function (ecdf), and ecdf are stepwise functions by definition (as it computes the CDF *on the values observed* in the sample).

Usually, smoothing of the ROC curve is done via binning. You could bin the score values and compute an *approximate* ROC curve, or you could bin the False Positive Rate values obtained by the actual ROC curve (i.e. bin the `X` values generated by `perfcurve()`) which generates a smooth version that *preserves the area under the curve* (`AUC`).

In the following example I will show and compare the smoothed ROC curves obtained from these two options, which can be accomplished using the `TVals` option and the `XVals` option of the `perfcurve` function, respectively.

In each case, the binning is done so that we get approximately equal-sized (*equal* in the number of cases) bins using the `tiedrank` function. The values to use for the `TVals` and the `XVals` options are then computed using the `grpstats` function as the `max` value on each bin of the original/pre-binned variable (`scores` or `X`, respectively).

```
%% Reference for the original ROC curve example: https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/perfcurve.html
load fisheriris
pred = meas(51:end,1:2);
resp = (1:100)'>50;  % Versicolor = 0, virginica = 1
mdl = fitglm(pred,resp,'Distribution','binomial','Link','logit');
scores = mdl.Fitted.Probability;
[X,Y,T,AUC] = perfcurve(species(51:end,:),scores,'virginica');  
AUC

%% Define the number of bins to use for smoothing
nbins = 10;

%% Option 1 (RED): Smooth the ROC curve by defining score thresholds (based on equal-size bins of the score).
scores_grp = ceil(nbins * tiedrank(scores(:,1)) / length(scores));
scores_thr = grpstats(scores, scores_grp, @max);
[X_grpScore,Y_grpScore,T_grpScore,AUC_grpScore] = perfcurve(species(51:end,:),scores,'virginica','TVals',scores_thr);   
AUC_grpScore

%% Option 2 (GREEN) Smooth the ROC curve by binning the False Positive Rate (variable X of the perfcurve() output)
X_grp = ceil(nbins * tiedrank(X(:,1)) / length(X));
X_thr = grpstats(X, X_grp, @max);
[X_grpFPR,Y_grpFPR,T_grpFPR,AUC_grpFPR] = perfcurve(species(51:end,:),scores,'virginica','XVals',X_thr);   
AUC_grpFPR

%% Plot
figure
plot(X,Y,'b.-'); hold on
plot(X_grpScore,Y_grpScore,'rx-')
plot(X_grpFPR,Y_grpFPR,'g.-')
xlabel('False positive rate')
ylabel('True positive rate')
title('ROC for Classification by Logistic Regression')
legend({'Original ROC curve', ...
        sprintf('Smoothed ROC curve in %d bins (based on score bins)', nbins), ...
        sprintf('Smoothed ROC curve in %d bins (based on FPR bins)', nbins)}, ...
        'Location', 'SouthEast')
```

The graphical output from this code is the following:
[image]

**Note**: if you look at the text output generated by the above code, you will notice that, as anticipated, the `AUC` values for the original ROC and the smoothed ROC curve based on FPR bins (GREEN option) coincide (`AUC = 0.7918`), whereas the `AUC` value for the smoothed ROC curve based on score bins (RED option) is quite smaller than the original AUC (`= 0.6342`), so the FPR approach should be preferred as smoothing technique for plotting purposes. Note however that the FPR approach requires computing the ROC curve twice, once on the original `scores` variable, and once on the binned FPR values (`X` values of the first ROC calculation).
However, the second ROC calculation can be avoided because the same smoothed ROC curve can be obtained by binning the `X` values and computing the `max(Y)` value on each bin, as shown in the following snippet:

```
%% Compute max(Y) on the binned X values
% Make a dataset with the X and Y variables as columns (for easier manipulation and grouping)
ds = dataset(X,Y);
% Compute equal size bins on X and the corresponding MAX statistics
ds.X_grp = ceil(nbins * tiedrank(ds.X(:,1)) / size(ds.X,1));
ds_grp = grpstats(ds, 'X_grp', @max, 'DataVars', {'X', 'Y'});
% Add the smooth curve to the previous plot
hold on
plot(ds_grp.max_X, ds_grp.max_Y, 'mx-')
```

And now you should see the above plot where the green curve has been overridden by a magenta curve with star points.